# Onboard Memory of USB HID Devices "hackable"?

Tags: memory, usb

I own some mice and keyboards for example my logitech G400 mouse and my razer deathstalker keyboard.

Both of those devices have as far as i know built in memories to save DPI settings macros so on and so forth.

Now i have read somewhere some time ago that at some german hacker meeting a guy managed to save a keylogger to the onboard memory of a razer deathstalker keyboard.

My questions are:

1. Is the memory built into my razer deathstalker keyboard not secured by a razer digital signature so that it only allows a razer signed driver to save changes to it? Same question goes for my g400 logitech mouse.
2. In case there is none protection whtasoever how could i overwrite the memory by myself?
   It's a shame that i don't find the original article i read.

Comment: Saving DPI settings to the memory shouldn't require signatures because it's a harmless operation. What should is the fact of updating the firmware of the microcontroller of the mouse, it that's even possible which I doubt.

Comment: For your second question, if the manufacturer does indeed provide firmware updates you can reverse engineer the update utility and then create your own (potentially malicious) firmware. Congratulations, you just uncovered a BadUSB exploit on a mouse.

Comment: BUt i guess those updates needed to be signed with the razer Signature otherwise the keyboard wouldnot accept them since only a Razer worker would have the signature not everybody could hack it...right?

Comment: You assume they did it right, but they often don't and I'm pretty sure there is no signature involved, just plain security by obscurity that you can easily reverse engineer.